# Showing a message without closing actual dialog in Android

Tags: java, android

I've to do a pair of fixes to an Android app although I don't really know about Android, but I'm getting problems in something that I don't think should be that difficult, I just want that when an OK button is pressed and some conditions haven't been fulfilled it displays a message and keeps on the same screen until data is correct or the user cancels, but I've tried it for some time and whatever I try it always displays the message and after that a white screen appears, even trying to search for examples on the internet.

This is my code:

```
final AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);

        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams parms = new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        layout.setLayoutParams(parms);

        layout.setGravity(Gravity.CLIP_VERTICAL);
        layout.setPadding(2, 2, 2, 2);

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);
        tv.setText("Es necesario rellenar los datos solicitados a continuación para poder realizar su primer canje");
        tv.setPadding(40, 40, 40, 40);
        tv.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
        tv.setTextSize(20);

        EditText et = new EditText(this);
        String etStr = et.getText().toString();
        TextView tv1 = new TextView(this);
        tv1.setText("Nombre completo");

        EditText et2 = new EditText(this);
        String etStr2 = et2.getText().toString();
        TextView tv2 = new TextView(this);
        tv2.setText("Teléfono");

        final EditText et3 = new EditText(this);
        String etStr3 = et3.getText().toString();
        TextView tv3 = new TextView(this);
        tv3.setText("Correo electrónico");

  LinearLayout.LayoutParams tv1Params = new    LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        tv1Params.bottomMargin = 5;
        layout.addView(tv1,tv1Params);
        layout.addView(et, new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,  LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(tv2,tv1Params);
        layout.addView(et2, new   LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
        layout.addView(tv3,tv1Params);
        layout.addView(et3, new  LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));


        alertDialogBuilder.setView(layout);
        alertDialogBuilder.setTitle("hola");
        // alertDialogBuilder.setMessage("Input Student ID");
        alertDialogBuilder.setCustomTitle(tv);


        // alertDialogBuilder.setMessage(message);
        alertDialogBuilder.setCancelable(true);

        // Setting Negative "Cancel" Button
        alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

 alertDialogBuilder.setNegativeButton("Cancel",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

[more code here]

 alertDialogBuilder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {



                matcher = pattern.matcher(et3.getText().toString());

                if (matcher.matches())
                {
                    [more code here]
                    }
                    else
                     {
   Toast.makeText( contexto, "Por favor, introduzca un e-mail válido", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
```

Hope you can help me with this thing, as I would find pretty annoying to have to learn android from the beginning to make something that I've been able to do in another programming languages in 5 minutes or less without knowing them at all.

Comment: If you dont want to learn android, maybe you should've told that to  your boss before you got assigned task related to android programming...

Answer (score 0):

First of all create your layouts using xml and inflate the view like this:

```
LayoutInflater li = (LayoutInflater) <ACTIVITY_NAME>.this
    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.<LAYOUT_NAME>, parent, false);
```

or

```
View view = li.inflate(R.layout.<LAYOUT_NAME>, null);
```

If there is no parent view to attach the inflated view to. Then you can edit objects in your view by doing:

```
EditText edit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit1);
edit.setText("example");
```

Doing so just makes your code much more cleaner.

The methods: `setPositiveButton`, `setNeutralButton` and `setNegativeButton` are coded so that when they are pressed, the dialog will close after it has finished executing the code in the listener.

If your Android app is running on the main thread for over 5 seconds then the app will throw an error saying that the app is no longer responding. If you wished to do a long action then you should use an `AsyncTask` or a `Service`.

I believe you are wanting to have a progress bar of some kind. I will link you to a 
tutorial that will show you how to acheive that side of things. [Check here](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBackgroundProcessing/article.html)

Hopefully this points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

Create two instance variables or class varibles like this

```
private Toast toast;
private boolean stop = false;
```

Write a method called this

```
private void showInfiniteToast() {
    stop = false;
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (!stop) {
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
                        toast.cancel();
                        return;
                    }
                    sleep(1850);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Infinite Toast", "Error "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}
```

Now in the oncreate create the toast and call this method

```
toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
showInfiniteToast();
```

Now if you want to change the toast message use this

```
toast.setText("message");
```

To stop the toast call any of these

```
//Call anyone of them
stop = true;
toast.cancel();
```

To implement your own custom view use this

```
View mView; 
LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)   getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE); 
mView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.mylayout, null);
toast.setView(mView);
```

Here is the complete file

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {

Button btnChange, btnStop, btnShow;
private Toast toast;
private boolean stop = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    btnShow = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnShow);
    btnShow.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnChange = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnChange);
    btnChange.setOnClickListener(this);
    btnStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnStop);
    btnStop.setOnClickListener(this);

    toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Test",
            Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
    showInfiniteToast();

}


private void showInfiniteToast() {
    stop = false;
    Thread t = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
            try {
                while (true) {
                    if (!stop) {
                        toast.show();
                    } else {
                        toast.cancel();
                        return;
                    }
                    sleep(1850);
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e("Infinite Toast", "Error "+ e.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        }
    };
    t.start();
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.btnShow:
        showInfiniteToast();
        break;
    case R.id.btnChange:
        toast.setText("Added");

        break;
    case R.id.btnStop:
        stop = true;
        toast.cancel();
        break;

    default:
        break;
    }
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

create a dialogBuilder, and override the negative and positive buttons, and on the click listeners do whatever you want. This will prevent the dialog from closing.

Like this:
Create the builder, intialize it, set it for eg:

```
builder.setView(view);
builder.setCancelable(false);
```

override the ondismiss listener, and onshow listener like:

```
builder.setOnDismissListener(new OnDismissListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDismiss(DialogInterface dialog) {
        if(!errorFlag) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }
    }   
});



builder.setOnShowListener(new OnShowListener() {
    @Override
    public void onShow(DialogInterface dialog) {
        Button b = builder.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                // write the logic here, and maintain a flag.
                // if the flag is true then only dismiss the dialog else show another one
            }
```

Override the negative button also.

show the builder using `builder.show()`

Comment: cannot resolve method : `builder.setOnShowListener()`.